# How to select the contrary of a specific regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Important**: Without a not operator

I need to select everything that this regex doesnt match

```
 /^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+/gm
```

- This shouldnt match (this is what is currently being matched): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCfufAp2tM
- This should match (this is what currently isnt being matched): randomwords

Comment: `if (testString.match(/regex/) === null) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the NOT operator?

```
!"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCfufAp2tM".match(/^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+/gm)
```

Returns false

```
!"randomwords".match(/^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+/gm)
```

Returns true

EDIT: looks like you won't use the NOT operator, so another way of doing is reverse the regex with `?!` operator like so:

```
/^(?!(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+)/gm
```

Comment: I should have added without using a not operator

Comment: I edited my answer to add another solution

Comment: [Your regex is invalid](https://regex101.com/r/56Gwg0/1).

Comment: Right, I misplaced parenthesis, shouldve double checked :)

Comment: thanks, will accept